# Who is the nearest neighbor of Corwyn?

Tags: deryni-series

In *The King's Deryni*, Alaric Morgan's Aunt Delphine says:

> You will wish to learn at least a little Torenthi, since Corwyn's
> nearest neighbor outside of Gwynedd is Torenth.

On the map, it does appear that Gwynedd borders Torenth.

Later in the same book, King Brion says to Alaric:

> The Hort of Orsal is also Prince of Tralia, just across the strait:
> your nearest neighbor,

So....which is it?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f051G.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wvfO.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Whereabouts would the M4 go through?

Comment: @Spencer - lol. It would head just north of Bristol, aka the ancient and noble city of Vezaire.

Comment: @Valorum Whose residents would go on holiday to Fianna, I suppose.

Comment: @Valorum - thanks.  I've seen the maps in several of the books.  Torenth appears to border Corwyn on the north, and Tralia on the east, but it is not really clear where the borders of Torenth are.  Either way, the text discrepancies stand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer likely depends on if you are talking about actual distance verses traveling time by medieval methods.  The Duchy of Corwyn Shares it's Eastern boarder with the Kingdom of Torenth. More specifically the Counties of Fathane and Sostra. A mountain range called the Coamer Mountains separate the whole western border of Torenth from the Eastern boarder of Gwynedd. Corwyn is the Duchy in the South-Eastern portion of Gwynedd. Quote from the *Codex Derynianus*:

> The County of Sostra is bounded on the North by the County of Medras,
> on the Northeast by the Duchy of Altorf, on the East by the Duchy of
> Csorna, On the South by the County of Fathane, and on **the West by
> the Duchy of Corwyn in Gwynedd**.

The County of Fathane shares the most Southern part of this Border.
Quote from the *Codex Derynianus*:

> 'Ships from Torenth and Corwyn traded there(the Port town of
> Fathane)regularly, and it was also a point of departure for hunters
> and trappers going further upriver to the great Verldur forests.'...
> It is here that Sean Earl Derry spent a night at the Crooked Dragon
> Inn and the Jack Dog Tavern on the 24th day of March in the Year 1121.
> This city was also used as a staging area for Torenthi Raids on Corwyn
> that spring.

So the answer to your question, as the crow flies in distance, is Torenth. But traveling to Torenth from Corywn is not an easy task. There are only two mountain passes that allow you to travel on foot from one to the other. A southern pass between Corwyn and Fathane which takes Lord Derry two days to travel, and a more northern pass near the town of Rengarth. These passes are closed in the winter months by snow.

> The great natural barrier between the two kingdoms has protected each
> from invasion, and has, at the same time, discouraged a more normal
> commerce, which may be one reason why Torenth and Gwynedd have
> remained so separate during their histories.

(*Codex Derynianus* under "Coamer Mountains")

So even though the two kingdoms are closest, they are hard to get from one to the other.

The Isles of Orsal and Sovereign Principality of the Hort of Orsal on the other hand is the fastest to reach by ship, and travel is available year around. From harbor to harbor on a good day it is only a three hour sail. Orsal guards the southern shore of the Twin river delta. Coroth (Corwyn's main city) guards the Northern shore of the Twin River delta. The two leaders have a treaty to monitor this main trade route between the Southern Sea and the twin rivers. Because there is normally a cross wind through this region, Sailing from Coroth to Orsal and back is an easy matter that can be made in one day and at nearly any time of the year.

Therefore, to answer your question about who is the closest in medieval modes of  travel and time, the answer would be The Hort of Orsal.

In response to the discrepancy, consider that it is actual characters in the book who are expressing their own Points of View. Alaric's Aunt is telling Alaric that he needs to learn the language of the people who might some day invade his duchy, and therefore calls them the closest neighbor.  Where as the King of Gwynedd is considering trade agreements and travel distance and therefore is saying that is Corwyn's closest neighbor. It is not necessarily a discrepancy made by the Author's background narrative. Different characters are allowed to have Different opinions.

Comment: Hi Laurna.  Welcome to SF&F and thank you!  -- Liesel

Comment: I edited the formatting of the quotes to make it clearer.  Please check that I was true to the correct  beginnings and endings of the quotes.